# how to use spring scala to decouple?

Tags: spring, scala

I like to add Spring to my Scala projects for educational purposes. But I do not understand the advantage of Spring Scala to decouple components.

I have created a simple configuration:

```
import org.springframework.scala.context.function.FunctionalConfiguration

class Configuration extends FunctionalConfiguration {
  bean() {
    new Service()
  }
}
```

and a simple service:

```
class Service {
  def method = "Bonjour tout le monde!"
}
```

and then an application which uses both:

```
import org.springframework.scala.context.function.FunctionalConfigApplicationContext

object Application extends App {
    implicit val context = FunctionalConfigApplicationContext(classOf[Configuration])

    val service = context.getBean(classOf[Service])
    println(service.method)
}
```

This is just my interpretation and implementation of the Spring Scala examples.

My application still has knowledge of the Service class. I could just write:

```
val service = new Service() // instead of asking for a Bean which has classname Service
println(service.method)
```

with the same effect.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I would understand, and tried to change to, if  bean("sophisticatedService") { ... } was possible, and used to textually define the bean, and then to use: context.getBean("sophisticatedService"). Since it is now decoupled by a textual name.

Comment: The only problem really solved by Spring for me was cyclic dependencies. But then I moved to using lazy vals (to avoid null's) and passing injected parameter by name inside constructor. So, don't use spring IoC anymore. Some people like `@Autowired` thing, but you can use traits for that (define dependency inside trait and mix it to some context where this dependency is already defined) - see more by googling `Cake pattern`

Comment: You can use spring for cases that you have interface for service and couple of implementations e.g your application will have dependency on UserRepository. You can have FileUserRepository implementation and your application is completely decoupled of that detail. Later you can implement DatabaseUserRepository and switch implementation without touching your code or you can use mock for testing and still code which is depending on UserRepository stays untouched.

Comment: A big advantage of DI (whether spring or using Scala constructs) is that you can program against an interface. When you go to unit test you can mock out the object and just test specific logic. e.g. You could provide a mock object for service that returns defined responses.

Answer (score 0):

This does decouple your use of the `Service` from the instantiation of it. E.g. if in the future `Service` changes to depend on some other `InnerService`, or has some initialization that can't be done in the constructor for some reason but needs to happen in a method call before it's used (`.connectToDatabase()` or some such), or if you wanted to replace the `Service` with a mock one for testing, then you can do this without changing these two lines of code:

```
val service = context.getBean(classOf[Service])
println(service.method)
```

If you program to an interface rather than implementation, e.g.

```
trait IService {
  def method: String
}
class Service extends IService...

val service = context.getBean(classOf[IService])
```

then you also make it easy to swap out the `Service` for a different implementation, though given the extra lines of code I probably wouldn't bother doing this until I actually had more than one implementation.

I'm not sure that Spring carries its own weight (it's a very large and complex library), particularly in Scala with its more concise constructor syntax. But whether you use Spring or not, it's worth separating the construction of your dependencies and "wiring up" of your application from their actual use. IMO a class `Foo` that uses `Service` should accept it, explicitly via its constructor, `class Foo(service: Service)`, and leave the construction/initialization of `Service` to a class/or function dedicated to that.